# Server resource pack not loading & resets server.properties

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm trying to load a server resource-pack on my local spigot server.

```
resource-pack=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dvpx9d1vtnobkzv/Pixel_Perfection_V3_6.zip?dl=1
```

When I launch the server there are no errors, the resource pack doesn't load and when I close the server the server.properties file has removed the resource-pack setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `:` character

```
resource-pack=https\://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dvpx9d1vtnobkzv/Pixel_Perfection_V3_6.zip?dl=1
```

I think I remember it right this was enough to make it working, so try it out :)

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was a syntax problem but could not find a definitive answer for this elsewhere.

Comment: I am also kinda surprised that this is not covered on MC wiki or so, wanted to include some source link, but well... :)